# GTK#-related error on MonoDevelop 2.8.5 on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: mono, monodevelop, ubuntu-11.04, gtk#

When I try to create a new solution in MonoDevelop 2.8.5 in Ubuntu 11.04 x64, it shows me:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
  at System.IO.Path.Combine (System.String path1, System.String path2) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Core.FilePath.Combine (System.String[] paths) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation.get_BinPath () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.DotNetProject..ctor (System.String languageName, MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation projectCreateInfo, System.Xml.XmlElement projectOptions) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.DotNetAssemblyProject..ctor (System.String languageName, MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation projectCreateInfo, System.Xml.XmlElement projectOptions) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.DotNetProjectBinding.CreateProject (System.String languageName, MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation info, System.Xml.XmlElement projectOptions) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.DotNetProjectBinding.CreateProject (MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation info, System.Xml.XmlElement projectOptions) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectService.CreateProject (System.String type, MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation info, System.Xml.XmlElement projectOptions) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.ProjectDescriptor.CreateItem (MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation projectCreateInformation, System.String defaultLanguage) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.ProjectTemplate.HasItemFeatures (MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionFolder parentFolder, MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectCreateInformation cinfo) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Projects.NewProjectDialog.SelectedIndexChange (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I `strace`'d it and saw repeated failed accesses to files like:

```
/usr/lib/mono/gac/gtk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.la
```

so I'm assuming that's the cause of the problem.

However, I've installed (and re-installed) anything GTK#-related that I could think of... and the error still occurs.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: have you filed a bug?  sounds like you need to reinstall monodevelop and gtk#

Answer (score 2):

A get it resolved by setting permission in directory and creating the directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:
1) Click on Start new solution.
2) Before select the solution type, select a location.
3) Select the solution type.
4) Select name.
It works for me in Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 0):

I [just released](https://plus.google.com/100402709180247864944/posts/2CjiDzFYQr2) a set of packages for ubuntu 11.10, they might also work on 11.04.

Add the following to your /etc/apt/sources.list:-

```
deb http://void.printf.net/~bredroll/pmono ./
```

Simply install everything like so:-

```
$ sudo apt-get update $ sudo apt-get install pmono-scripts pmono-monodevelop
```

This is a [parallel mono installation](http://www.mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments) so won't conflict or interact with the existing mono.

This only includes MD 2.8.2 but it seems to work well for me.  When I find more time I'll update MD to 2.8.5

Comment: try my packages, they now work quite well ( release 4 today ) </plug>